# Run a program on a specific time using python

Tags: python

I want to run a batch file(say wanted to run calculator) on a specific date and time using python (but don't use the default scheduler).
My program:

```
a = "C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe"
mybat = open(r"D:\Cyber_security\Python\cal.bat", "w+")
mybat.write(a)
mybat.close()
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime.now()

end = datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 12, 17, 29, 10)
while(True):
    if(end - start == 0):
        import subprocess
        subprocess.call([r"D:\Cyber_security\Python\cal.bat"])
```

when I run it it doesn't show error but the batch file is not running at specific time. where is the wrong?

Comment: Please post specific error message (stack trace)

Comment: `start` is never updated. It'll always contain the time when you launched the script, so `end - start` will be a constant.

Comment: There is no error message....

Comment: Then ForceBru is correct. 'start' is never updated. In addition, the way it is handled, the cpu clogging will be insane. I suggest adding a 'sleep(5)', then checking if 'end - start <= 0'.

Comment: Better yet, please view this question, for a better implementation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121539/run-function-at-a-specific-time-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found my answer.

```
a = "C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe"
mybat = open(r"D:\Cyber_security\Python\cal.bat", "w+")
mybat.write(a)
mybat.close()
import sched
from datetime import datetime
import time
def action():
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call([r"D:\Cyber_security\Python\cal.bat"])
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
e_x = s.enterabs(time.strptime('Tue Jul 12 19:57:17 2022'), 0, action)
s.run()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Ever tried [schedule package](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/)?

```py
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job)
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
schedule.every(5).to(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().monday.do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)
schedule.every().minute.at(":17").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [Rocketry](https://rocketry.readthedocs.io/)?

```
from rocketry import Rocketry

app = Rocketry()

@app.task('every 1 hour')
def do_hourly():
    ...

@app.task('daily between 10:00 and 14:00 & time of week on Monday')
def do_once_a_day_on_monday():
    ...

@app.task("after task 'do_hourly'")
def do_after_another():
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

It also has parametrization, parallelization and Pythonic conditions if you dislike the string-based condition language.

- Documentation: https://rocketry.readthedocs.io/
- Source code: https://github.com/Miksus/rocketry

Comment: Hello miksus, I've been using your app recently and it's flexibility really amazes me. What I'm trying to figure out now is to run a task at a specific time. Is it possible?

Comment: actually my question is if `daily` runs the task every day? and is it possible to say start running a task at a specific time but with a defined interval??